# Direction Angles of a vector

Tags: geometry, vectors, vector-analysis

According to what I have read the direction angles of a given vector can only be acute or obtuse. Why can they never be a reflex angle? as per the definition of direction angle it is the angle formed by the vector with unit coordinate vector I, j or k, then wouldn't a vector pointing  diagonally in the 3rd or 4rth quadrant have a direction angle with the unit vector 'i' greater than 180 that is a reflex angle??

Comment: "Direction angles" is an old wording, that now few people use. You should say that you want to represent the coordinates of a unit vector under the form $(x,y,z)=(\cos(a),\cos(b),\cos(c))$ and you wonder why we restrict $a,b,c$ to be in $[0,\pi]$ ? Is that right ? A first answer is : because it is sufficient to cover all cases.

Comment: But if the vector is in the 3rd/4rth quad then??